# How to compress three-color pictures efficiently

Tags: java, image-compression

In my applicaiton, there are many two-color and three-color pictures. Two-color pictures are black and white, I convert the picture into monochrome mode, from 8-bit to 1-bit. Three-color pictures are black, white and red. Is there a similar mechasim to convert the picture into 2-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're looking for an [indexed color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color) storage model, with 2-bit index values, so each byte stores 4 pixels.

From the linked Wikipedia article:

> [image: indexed color]
>
> A 2-bit indexed color image. The color of each pixel is represented by a number; each number (the index) corresponds to a color in the color table (the palette).

Comment: Very nice visuals Andreas.  You often impress.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this would be to encode the 3 color black-white-red image as two 2 color images:

- a black / white image where 1 represents black
- a red / not red image where 1 represents red

For example the colors can be mapped as follows:

- black -> (1, 0)
- white -> (0, 0)
- red -> (?, 1) where ? can be either 0 or 1.

The two 2 color images can then be compressed / decompressed separately.  3 color <-> 2 color conversion can be performed by simple pixel filtering and combining operations.  The latter could be beneficial if the transforms need to be done on a GPU.

(The information density of this representation is the same as Andreas' indexed color storage model.  2 bits represent each pixel in the original image.)